# PATH environment variables different in activated virtual environment

Tags: python, macos, path, environment-variables, pythonpath

I've noticed when I get traceback errors in *any* project, the file path in the trace shows one specific project I no longer use. For example:

```
File "/Users/MyComputer/Developer/SampleApp/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py"...
```

I'm assuming the site-packages are not suppose to be from SampleApp, correct? I do use virtual environments in all my projects. When I run `echo $PATH` while in an **activated** virtual environment I get:

```
/Users/MyComputer/Developer/SampleApp/venv/bin: #<----- Shouldn't point to a specific project! 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:
/Users/MyComputer/bin/:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/bin:
/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/sbin:
/usr/local/git/bin:
/Users/MyComputer/.rvm/bin:
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin
```

When I run `echo $PATH` in a **deactivated** virtual environment I get the above without `/Users/MyComputer/Developer/SampleApp/venv/bin`.

Here is what is in my `./bashrc`:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/usr/local/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/usr/bin/env
```

Here's what is in my `.bash_profile`:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

# Postgres.app
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin

# Setting PATH for Python 3.5
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Why is the activated venv path different from a deactivated env? Thank you in advance! :)